# How to get the range/innerHtml of an item when item is drag to timeline vis.js?

Tags: html, angularjs, timeline, vis.js

1.I have an items in one div

2.I am dragging that items  and dropping in the timeline.

3.so At the time of dropping.I want to get the timeline range of that particular item.

4. I used ng-draggable,timeline vis.js libraries.

Items in  one div code :

```
<div class="timeline-elements-left-column">
                <md-card class="timeline-elements-container"
                             ng-repeat="element in vm.elementAndStages">
                    <md-toolbar md-scroll-shrink class="timeline-selected-elements drag-object">
                        <div layout="row"
                             id="translation-icon-move"
                             ng-drag="vm.isDragging"
                             ng-mousedown="vm.StartDragging(element, event)"
                             ng-drag-data="element">
                            <div flex class="timeline-selected-elements-text">
                                <span>{{element.selectedElement.description}}</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="timeline-selected-elements-icon">
                                <md-icon ng-show="element.selectedElement.collapsed"
                                         class="zmdi zmdi-chevron-up"
                                         ng-click="vm.Collapse(element.selectedElement)">
                                </md-icon>
                                <md-icon ng-hide="element.selectedElement.collapsed"
                                         class="zmdi zmdi-chevron-down"
                                         ng-click="vm.Collapse(element.selectedElement)">
                                </md-icon>
                            </div>
                            <div class="timeline-selected-elements-icon timeline-selected-elements-icon-drag">
                                <md-icon class="zmdi zmdi-more-vert"></md-icon>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </md-toolbar>
                </md-card>
            </div>
```

4.So here vm.StartDragging() is the function to Drag the event.

5. so at the time of start Dragging function

   function StartDragging(data:stage,event :any){

   console.log(this.timeline.getEventProperties(event));
    }

so at the time of dragging its working fine.

1. Problem is at drop-success.
2. Dropping success on timeline but I am unable to get that range where user is dropping the item in timeline.
3. Dropping code in Html

   ```
   <div class="vis-group" ng-drop="true" ng-drop-success="vm.OnDropComplete($index, $data, $event,0)" ng-drag-stop="vm.StopDragging($event)" id="group0" style="height: 173px;">
   ```
4. Here Dropping is fine.

   5.OnDropComplete function code

OnDropComplete(index :number,stage:any,event: any, groupId: number): void {

```
    var indexToRemove: number = -1;
    this.pendingChanges = [];
```

console.log(this.timeline.getEventProperties(event));
}

6. so console.log(this.timeline.getEventProperties(event)); this line generating error.Here Event is ok , but event.target is undefined.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tricky task you are trying to solve. Since the vis timeline is dynamic (can be zoomed or scrolled) you do not have a static point you can use as a referencing point to where the item is dropped.
When I tried to solve a similar issue I was using a combination of [document.getElementFromPoint()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementFromPoint)  (using the coordinates from the drop event) and the time axis in the timeline to get the nearest point to where the user dropped the item. Using those information, I would add the item at the specific place.

I hope this puts you on the right track.